# Trigger Kubernetes job on secret update

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-jobs

How do you trigger rerunning a job once one of its dependent secrets get updated?

For example, say I have this simple job:

```yaml
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-test
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: databricks
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: job-test
        image: alpine
        command:
          - echo
          - hello $(DAN_TEST)
        env:
          - name: DAN_TEST
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: dan-test
                key: dan-test-1
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Adding this job makes it run and print out the secret, but when the secret is changed, the job is not automatically rerun.

Is there built-in or 3rd party extension resource that can target the secret and the job and trigger a rerun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`stakater/Reloader`](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader) allows resources to be reloaded based on watched changes in a `ConfigMap` or `Secret`.

Unfortunately, [`Job` and `CronJob` resources are not supported](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader/issues/295), so to make it work I used a `Deployment` with an `initContainer` which executed the job, and a `container` which kept the pod alive.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: job-test
  labels:
    app: job-test
  annotations:
    reloader.stakater.com/auto: "true"
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: job-test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: job-test
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: job-test
          image: alpine
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          command:
            - echo
            - hello $(DAN_TEST)
          env:
            - name: DAN_TEST
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: dan-test
                  key: dan-test-1
      containers:
        - name: job-test-wait
          image: alpine
          command:
            - tail
            - -f
            - /dev/null
```

I forgot exactly why the pod needed to be kept alive, but from trial and error this is what I got working a few months ago and am still using today.

Comment: "I forgot exactly why the pod needed to be kept alive" - it's because the "reloader" reboots deployments so you need to keep it alive so its rebooted. If it had no pods it would not be rebooted. This is quite smart and exactly what I needed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's maybe better to use a `ConfigMap` instead of a `Secret`, because `ConfigMaps` are designed to be more easily updated and can be monitored for changes using Kubernetes' built-in watch functionality!

let me update your code again :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: job-test
  annotations:
    configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload: "dan-test"
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: databricks
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: job-test
        image: alpine
        command:
          - echo
          - hello $(DAN_TEST)
        env:
          - name: DAN_TEST
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: dan-test
                key: dan-test-1
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

as you can see,I'm using the "configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload" annotation to tell Kubernetes to monitor the "dan-test" ConfigMap for changes.
and about third-party tools, the "Kubernetes Event-Driven Autoscaling" (KEDA) project includes a "Secret" scaler that can trigger a Job based on changes to a Secret or other tools like `Argo Workflows` also provide similar functionality.

**update :**
Ok I think to automatically trigger a rerun of a Job when a ConfigMap or Secret it depends on is updated, you can use the `cronjob` resource instead of the `job` resource

Let me explain cronjob to you with this example :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-test
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *" # run every minute
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: job-test
            image: alpine
            command:
              - echo
              - hello $(DAN_TEST)
            env:
            - name: DAN_TEST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: dan-test
                  key: dan-test-1
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

As you see,`restartPolicy` is set to `OnFailure`, which means that the `cronjob` will automatically rerun the `job` if it fails, and also to trigger a rerun of the `cronjob` when the `dan-test` ConfigMap is updated, you can use the `configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload` annotation on the `cronjob`

Something like this (but be careful if the `cronjob` is already running when the ConfigMap is updated, the `job` may be in progress and cannot be interrupted. In this scenario, you will need to delete the `job` manually to trigger a rerun) :

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: job-test
  annotations:
    configmap.reloader.stakater.com/reload: "dan-test"
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: job-test
            image: alpine
            command:
              - echo
              - hello $(DAN_TEST)
            env:
            - name: DAN_TEST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: dan-test
                  key: dan-test-1
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

good luck !

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! This put me on the right track but I'm just shy of completing my goal. The issue is that this does not work for `Job` resources, only `Deployment`, `DeploymentConfig`, `Daemonset`, `Statefulset`, and `Rollout`. (Also, secrets are supported via `secret.reloader.stakater.com/reload` annotation or the `reloader.stakater.com/{auto, search, match}` annotations). The issue is, deployments try to keep the pod running. When it terminates it tries to restart it. Currently looking for how to configure this.

Comment: There is an [open issue](https://github.com/stakater/Reloader/issues/295) asking to add support to `Job`s. Unfortunately, [`Deployment`s don't support a value for `.spec.template.spec.restartPolicy` other than `Always`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#pod-template). To hack this, what I did was add an `initContainer` in conjunction with a regular container that just hangs with `tail -f /dev/null`.

Comment: @DanielI updated my question again, but please confirm my answer or create a new topic because it seems that this topic has become too cluttered and confusing.

Comment: @Freeman - Read through stakaters documentation it doesn't seem like there exists a trigger , i.e. change in config map / secret wouldn't trigger a job/cronjob. But if we're to use Deployment , the references to these secrets and configmaps are updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Freeman! I'm not sure if you read what I wrote, but stakater/Reloader does not support Job and CronJob currently so your proposed solutions do not work. I'm not sure what you mean by the topic being too cluttered and confusing, the goal is simple and clear: retrigger jobs when a secret changes. I don't know what creating a new topic will achieve except cause it to be closed as duplicate to this one. I posted an answer with my hack I mentioned in the comments. This is what I'm using now and it is working.